# Trigger test issue: opportunity amount becomes null in trigger also it's set in test class, other fields retain set value

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I developed a trigger to calculate converted amount in a multi-currency setup, and store the value in a custom field called `Converted_Currency__c` on the opportunity.

The trigger works perfectly in Sandbox, but to transport to production I need to add some tests.

I'm facing a very weird issue when running the test. In the test I set different value on the opportunity, and insert the record to trigger the conversion code. When in test mode, the trigger code receives an opportunity with all fields set with correct value, except the amount field which is null. I used `System.debug` to better understand the problem. The log is available at the end of this post.

**Trigger:**

```
trigger MVPOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        DatedConversionRate conversionRateRecord = [
                SELECT ConversionRate
                FROM DatedConversionRate
                WHERE IsoCode = :opp.CurrencyIsoCode
                    AND StartDate <= :opp.CloseDate
                    AND NextStartDate > :opp.CloseDate
                LIMIT 1
        ];
        // Here amount is null !
        System.debug('Trigger: opp.Amount = ' + opp.Amount);
        System.debug('Trigger: conversionRateRecord.ConversionRate = ' + conversionRateRecord.ConversionRate);
        System.debug('Trigger: opp.Name = ' + opp.Name);
        System.debug('Trigger: opp.CurrencyIsoCode =' + opp.CurrencyIsoCode);
        opp.Converted_Amount__c = (opp.Amount / conversionRateRecord.ConversionRate).setScale(2);
    }   
}
```

**Test class:**

```
@isTest
public class TestMVPOpportunityTrigger {

    @isTest
    static void testConvertedAmountCalculation() {
        Test.startTest();
        Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(
            Name = 'Test Opportunity',
            Amount = 1000,
            CurrencyIsoCode = 'CHF',
            CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2023, 1, 15)
        );
        // Here amount is 1000
        System.debug('Test: testOpp.Amount = ' + testOpp.Amount);
        System.debug('Test: testOpp.Name = ' + testOpp.Name);
        System.debug('Test: testOpp.CurrencyIsoCode =' + testOpp.CurrencyIsoCode);
        insert testOpp;

        testOpp = [SELECT Converted_Amount__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :testOpp.Id];
        System.assertEquals(1000, testOpp.Converted_Amount__c);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

**Logs filter on USER_DEBUG**

[image: Log output filter on USER_DEBUG]

As shown in the log, all fields that were set in Test class are retained on this opportunity while in trigger, except the Amount fields which becomes null.

Not sure where to look and what could cause this? Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Salesforce [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), the only thing that runs before the `before` triggers, is record-triggered flows. Check there are any Flows active. Also check if there are any other `before` triggers on Opportunity, as they may be running first. (The order in which triggers run is not guaranteed)

As an aside, you probably want to [bulkify](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) your trigger. You are doing a SOQL query for every record in your trigger and that will hit limits if lots of opportunities are inserted at once.

Comment: or, multiple triggers on Opportunity where order of execution is non-deterministic

Comment: @cropredy I already said that in my answer or do you mean something else?

Comment: oops -- I didn't read carefully enough -- my bad; I wish I could delete the comment

Comment: No worries. I have made my answer clearer as a result!

Comment: Thanks Fred! There was effectively a record triggered flow changing the value of the amount. It should not have been running as per the values in the record but it was. After deactivating it the test ran without problem. Now with updated conditions and after reactivation it's all OK. Thank you all for your help !

Comment: And by the way as you said, I quickly had to bulkify my code as it was breaking after 100 inserts. Good spot!